# Junit AWS EC2 Test

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, junit

Is there a way test the AWS EC2 in a unit test?

I have to test start/stop/terminate.
I found the library [aws-mock](https://github.com/treelogic-swe/aws-mock) but it seems to be not working. I have tried the example unit test found [here](https://github.com/treelogic-swe/aws-mock/blob/master/example/java/test/TestExamples.java).

It doesn't start the mock server I think…

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247018/how-do-you-test-code-written-against-aws-api

Comment: @RafaelOsipov That's for S3 not for EC2.

Comment: probably the following links will be useful: https://www.openfoo.org/blog/aws_ec2_java_library_mock.html   and this:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46458

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into the aws thread! @RafaelOsipov

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Could you please give me an example how you would do this in this case?

Comment: have you checked [this post](https://www.openfoo.org/blog/aws_ec2_java_library_mock.html)? In this post there is a [link to sample code](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awscode/amazon-ec2/2009-08-15/java/library/doc/src-html/com/amazonaws/ec2/samples/DescribeImagesSample.html)

Comment: @RafaelOsipov but unfortunately **AmazonEC2Mock** is no longer included in the SDK

Comment: @StepDev have you seen [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

[localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) supports EC2 API. It may be not 100% compatible with the true AWS EC2 API, but should be enough for the tests.

And if you're using JUnit 5 for the tests, let me recommend you [JUnit 5 extensions for AWS](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc), a few JUnit 5 extensions that could be useful for testing AWS-related code. These extensions can be used to inject clients for AWS service clients provided by tools like localstack (or the real ones). Both AWS Java SDK v 2.x and v 1.x are supported.